# Automate string input to a input

Tags: javascript, input

I know this question has been asked a hundred times.
But once again, the solutions no longer work.

I need to simulate key presses to automate a form.

If I do it like this

```
document.getElementById("input_id").value = "testinput"
```

the events from the input do not trigger.
And my value is just deleted again.

is there again a possibility to simulate keystrokes so that also all events are triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the following code that works for me:

```
function set_value(doc, input_value) {
  doc.value === undefined ? doc.innerHTML = input_value : doc.value = input_value;
  events = ["keydown", "keypress", "input", "keyup", "change"]
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; ++i) doc.dispatchEvent(new Event(events[i], {
    bubbles: true
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch keyboard events on an [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) (element, Window, Document, others) like this:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'a'}));
```

Example:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('input');
element.onkeydown = e => alert(e.key);
changeValButton.onclick = () => element.value += "a";
dispatchButton.onclick = () => {
  element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'E'}));
  element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'key':'E'}));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="">
<button id="dispatchButton">Press to dispatch event </button>
<button id="changeValButton">Press to change value </button>
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work at all with me and my strange inputs I have here.
I can't make min one input an element.value += "a". This is simply not accepted.